# Global variable doesn't work on node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have simple javascript code and I don't understand why each time globalString is zero. Even after I call high. It should be global variable which will be same between method calls.

```
const express = require('express');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var test_out = "";
var globalString = 0;

app.post('/high', (req, res) => {
    globalString = 1;
    return res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok' , message: globalString.toString() });   
});


app.post('/low', (req, res) => {
    globalString = 0;
    return res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok' , message: globalString.toString() });   
});

app.post('/state', (req, res) => {
    globalString = 0;
    return res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok' , message: globalString.toString() });   
});
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server is up.'));
```

Comment: When exactly is it `0`? What are you referring to when you say "each time"? *"Even after I call high."* What are you doing after calling high? You are setting it to `0` in the `/low` and `/state` handlers.

Comment: I'm guessing the request for `/state` should be `.get()`, and it shouldn't set `globalString` to zero. Once you fix that, make the request for /high, then get /state and you'll find it works fine.

Comment: I tried your code out: `http://localhost:4000/high` returns `{"result":"ok","message":"1"}`

Comment: LUKE, in case you missed this: your code is deliberately setting the variable to 0 in every route but `/high`; the question is, given how readable and simple the code is: how do you *not* understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in above comment " you are setting globalString 0 every time api get called"

```js
const express = require('express');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var test_out = "";
var globalString = 0;

app.post('/high', (req, res) => {
    globalString = 1;
    return res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok' , message: globalString.toString() });   
});


app.post('/low', (req, res) => {
    //globalString = 0; you are setting globalString 0 every time this api get called
    return res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok' , message: globalString.toString() });   
});

app.post('/state', (req, res) => {
    //globalString = 0;  you are setting globalString 0 every time this api get called
    return res.status(200).json({ result: 'ok' , message: globalString.toString() });   
});
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server is up.'));
```